# Oracle.DataAccess.Dll x64 support

Tags: oracle, data-access, odac

My oracle.dataaccess.dll is not supported on x64 machines.
I've looked for it everywhere - but all I could find is the x86 version.

Anyone knows where can I get it from?

Comment: look to http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2007/11/21/oracle-data-access-components-odac-with-64-bit-development/

Comment: Already read it. but it's from 2007... I want to know if something has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download "11107_w2k8_x64_production_client" from oracle and after installation you'll find the file in the installation's directory.

Here is the link:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/111070-win64-2008soft-084715.html

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/111070-win64-2008soft-084715.html